# How to backup sql relations for server re-installation?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, nginx

I am in need to re-install the nginx ubuntu 12.04 server I'm using in another machine. I've already got all the scripts (php,js,html, etc) so every data in the server is secured, but how can I do the same for the mysql relations? I don't care much for the data in those tables but I want to rescue all the relations and table structure so I just need to *drag-and-drop* to a new folder in the new server and automatically get everything going.

Comment: For Mysql i would use a backup/restore process

Comment: could you be more explanative please? I'm yet to become fully comfortable with these mecanisms...

Comment: Yes, perform a sql backup from the old server and restore it on the new server : http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php

Comment: @krisFR and will this work even if i **totally** erase everything I had on the server'

Comment: IF you still have the database available on the old server and if mysql is installed on the new server, yes it will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to backup your databases with -d switch, that way you will skip data backup and will only backup structure:

> mysqldump -d  -u root -p password dbname > dumpfile.sql

drag and drop is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

I will feel more secure using Mysql backup/restore mechanism instead of a file/folder copy.

1. First use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to backup your database on the old server

   ```
   mysqldump -u uname -ppass dbname > backupfile.sql
   ```
2. Then use [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html) or [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) to restore the database on the new
   server

   ```
   mysql -u uname -ppass db_to_restore < backupfile.sql
   OR
   mysqlimport -u uname -ppass dbname backupfile.sql
   ```

See also : http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php